# Bean Validation API

Tags: java, regex, spring, hibernate

Use Bean Validation API for validate object's for save in DB by Hibernate.
With english letters all fine:

```
@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z]+$",message="Имя автора только из букв")
private String name;
```

When i wrote this:

```
@Pattern(regexp="^[a-zа-яA-ZА-Я]+$", message="Имя автора только из букв")
private String name;
```

It's doesn't work, take error about wrong enter data (Имя автора только из букв)

But how add russian letters in regexp?

Yes, problem in Spring form. When remove regexp and enter russian text, it's write in database something like this ÐÐµÑÑÐ¾Ð²

Comment: Change the pattern to `regexp="^[\p{IsCyrillic}a-zA-Z]+$"`. See if that works!

Comment: @Octopus, guess you meant `regexp="^[\p{IsCyrillic}a-zA-Z]+$"`

Comment: not work, error in \p, because it is in string. if write like \\p, not work

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry ;) OP, Please see stema's comment.

Comment: Maybe instead of `IsCyrillic` try `InCyrillic`. Also could you post example of data you are not able to validate?

Comment: Maybe problem in something else. Because I'm try to enter all russian letters in regexp manually, like [абвгд...] And it's still not work. maybe problem in Spring form with whose help enter data.

Comment: You can test it easily. Just see result of `"dataYouWantToValidate".matches(regex)` in some simple Java application, to see if your regex is correct. If regex works there but not in Spring then problem most probably lies in Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by add this in web-app context:

```
     <filter>  
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
        <init-param>  
           <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
           <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
        <init-param>  
           <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>  
           <param-value>true</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
    </filter>  
    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>
```

and regexp like `[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]` work fine.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer. Also using `(?i)` flag will make regex case insensitive so maybe try `(?i)[a-zа-я]`.

Comment: I think `[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]` more understandable write.